# java script backspace and delete working in IE,not in FireFox

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome, backspace

I use the following function for decimal validation it was work fine in IE and Chrome not in FF.Backspace and delete key working in IE and Chrome.Not in FireFox

```
    $('.decimalValidate').live('keypress', function (e) {
        var decimalid = $(this).attr("id");
        var decimalval = $('#' + decimalid).val();

        var decimalvalidate = ApplyDecimalFilter(decimalval, e);
        if (decimalvalidate == false) return false;
    });



    function ApplyDecimalFilter(id, event)
        {
            try {
                return NewDecimalFilter(id, event);
            } catch (e) {
                alert(e.message);
            }
        }

    function NewDecimalFilter(o, event) {
            if (event.which > 47 && event.which < 58) {
                return true;
            }
            if (event.which == 50 ||(event.which == 8 || event.which == 46) && o.indexOf('.') == -1)  {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

this if condition not working in FireFox only.this is used to enter the only one dot symbol

```
if (event.which == 50 ||(event.which == 8 || event.which == 46) && o.indexOf('.') == -1)  {
                return true;
            }
```

Comment: Just wondering, what happens when a user pastes or drags text into your input field?  Without using the keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

In general, this type of validation needs to be done with care because text can be altered into an input via means other than the keyboard (pasting, text dragging and the Delete option in the context menu, for example). Limiting keyboard input will still need to be accompanied by proper validation when submitting the form.

Use `keyCode` for detecting the actual key pressed (usually in `keydown` or `keyup` rather than `keypress`) and `which` to detect the character typed (only in the `keypress` event). In general it's not a good idea to look at the `keyCode` property of `keypress` events but for the case of delete and backspace it's fine: not all browsers fire a `keypress` event for these keys but for those that do, the `keyCode` property is consistent.

In summary: change `(event.which == 8 || event.which == 46)` to `(event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 46)` and leave the rest the same.

Here's the best reference for JavaScript key events I've seen: http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('#Name_Var').keypress(function (event) {
    event = event || window.event;
    var charCode = event.which || event.keyCode;
    var charStr = String.fromCharCode(charCode);
    // FireFox key Del - Supr - Up - Down - Left - Right
    if (event.key !== undefined && event.charCode === 0) {
        return;
    }
    //Only Num
    if (!/^([0-9])*$/.test(charStr)) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    //Num and letters 
    if (!/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/.test(charStr)) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```